# Get C FILE pointer from bytes::Bytes in Rust

Tags: rust, ffi, libc, grib, reqwest

I would like to read a [GRIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB) file downloaded from server using [ecCodes](https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes) library in Rust. However, my current solution results in segmentation fault. The extracted example, replicating the problem, is below.

I download the file using `reqwest` crate and get the response as `Bytes`<sup>1</sup> using [`bytes()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.3/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes). To read the file with ecCodes I need to create a `codes_handle` using [`codes_grib_handle_new_from_file()`](http://download.ecmwf.int/test-data/eccodes/html/group__codes__handle.html#ga36de77229cc3b386d26c1e7b52c21e0e)<sup>2</sup>, which as argument requires `*FILE`  usually get from `fopen()`. However, I would like to skip IO operations. So I figured I could use [`libc::fmemopen()`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.97/libc/fn.fmemopen.html) to get `*FILE` from `Bytes`. But when I pass the `*mut FILE` from `fmemopen()` to `codes_grib_handle_new_from_file()` segmentation fault occurs.

I suspect the issue is when I get from `Bytes` a `*mut c_void` required by `fmemopen()`. I figured I can do this like that:

```rust
//get a *mut c_void pointer fom Bytes
//file has &Bytes type
let mut buf = BytesMut::from(file.as_ref());
let ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr();
let ptr = ptr as *mut c_void;
```

Because `*mut` is required, I create `BytesMut` from which I can then get mut pointer. I think those conversion are problematic, because in debugger info `ptr` contains a diffrent memory adress than `ptr` field of `file`.

Using `*FILE` got from `libc::fopen()` for the same file does not result in segfault. So the problem is somwhere around `fmemopen()`.

The ecCodes library is correctly built (passes all tests and works in C) and linked (the calls in callstack are correct).

The full extracted example:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(non_camel_case_types)]

use bytes::{Bytes, BytesMut};
use libc::{c_char, c_void, fmemopen, size_t, FILE};
use reqwest;
use tokio;

// generated by bindgen
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct codes_handle {
    _unused: [u8; 0],
}

// generated by bindgen
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct codes_context {
    _unused: [u8; 0],
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // download the grib file from server
    // then get response as bytes
    let url = "https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.20210612/00/atmos/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000";
    let file = reqwest::get(url).await.unwrap().bytes().await.unwrap();

    // get Bytes from *FILE with fmemopen
    // file must outlive the pointer so it is borrowed here
    let file_handle = open_with_fmemopen(&file);

    let grib_handle = open_with_codes(file_handle);
}

pub fn open_with_fmemopen(file: &Bytes) -> *mut FILE {
    // size of buffer and mode to be read with
    let size = file.len() as size_t;
    let mode = "r".as_ptr() as *const c_char;

    // get a *mut c_void pointer fom Bytes
    let mut buf = BytesMut::from(file.as_ref());
    let ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr();
    let ptr = ptr as *mut c_void;

    // get *FILE with fmemopen
    let obj;
    unsafe {
        obj = fmemopen(ptr, size, mode);
    }
    
    obj
}

pub fn open_with_codes(file_handle: *mut FILE) -> *mut codes_handle {
    
    // default context for ecCodes
    let context: *mut codes_context = std::ptr::null_mut();

    // variable to hold error code
    let mut error: i32 = 0;

    // get codes_handle from *FILE
    let grib_handle;
    unsafe {
        // segmentation fault occurs here
        grib_handle = codes_grib_handle_new_from_file(context, file_handle, &mut error as *mut i32);
    }

    grib_handle
}

// binding to ecCodes C library
#[link(name = "eccodes")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn codes_grib_handle_new_from_file(
        c: *mut codes_context,
        f: *mut FILE,
        error: *mut i32,
    ) -> *mut codes_handle;
}
```

And because the example might require considerable effort to set up I also attach the call stack from GDB of the seg fault:

```
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms 0x00007f738b415fa6
fmemopen_read 0x00007f738b31c9b4
_IO_new_file_underflow 0x00007f738b31fd51
__GI___underflow 0x00007f738b32142e
__GI___underflow 0x00007f738b32142e
__GI__IO_default_xsgetn 0x00007f738b32142e
__GI__IO_fread 0x00007f738b312493
stdio_read 0x00007f738bb8db37
_read_any 0x00007f738bb8cf1b
read_any 0x00007f738bb8cfa3
_wmo_read_any_from_file_malloc 0x00007f738bb8e6f7
wmo_read_grib_from_file_malloc 0x00007f738bb8e7d7
grib_handle_new_from_file_no_multi 0x00007f738bb872a2
grib_new_from_file 0x00007f738bb8678f
grib_handle_new_from_file 0x00007f738bb85998
codes_grib_handle_new_from_file 0x00007f738bb8532b
example::open_with_codes main.rs:68
example::main::{{closure}} main.rs:34
core::future::from_generator::{{impl}}::poll<generator-0> mod.rs:80
tokio::park::thread::{{impl}}::block_on::{{closure}}<core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<generator-0>> thread.rs:263
tokio::coop::with_budget::{{closure}}<core::task::poll::Poll<()>,closure-0> coop.rs:106
std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::Cell<tokio::coop::Budget>>::try_with<core::cell::Cell<tokio::coop::Budget>,closure-0,core::task::poll::Poll<()>> local.rs:272
std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::Cell<tokio::coop::Budget>>::with<core::cell::Cell<tokio::coop::Budget>,closure-0,core::task::poll::Poll<()>> local.rs:248
tokio::coop::with_budget<core::task::poll::Poll<()>,closure-0> coop.rs:99
tokio::coop::budget<core::task::poll::Poll<()>,closure-0> coop.rs:76
tokio::park::thread::CachedParkThread::block_on<core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<generator-0>> thread.rs:263
tokio::runtime::enter::Enter::block_on<core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<generator-0>> enter.rs:151
tokio::runtime::thread_pool::ThreadPool::block_on<core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<generator-0>> mod.rs:71
tokio::runtime::Runtime::block_on<core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<generator-0>> mod.rs:452
example::main main.rs:34
core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<fn(),()> function.rs:227
std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace<fn(),()> backtrace.rs:125
std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<()> rt.rs:66
core::ops::function::impls::{{impl}}::call_once<(),Fn<()>> function.rs:259
std::panicking::try::do_call<&Fn<()>,i32> panicking.rs:379
std::panicking::try<i32,&Fn<()>> panicking.rs:343
std::panic::catch_unwind<&Fn<()>,i32> panic.rs:431
std::rt::lang_start_internal rt.rs:51
std::rt::lang_start<()> rt.rs:65
main 0x0000560f1d93c76c
__libc_start_main 0x00007f738b2bb565
_start 0x0000560f1d935f0e
```

---

<sup>1</sup> From `bytes` crate, not `std::io` 
<sup>2</sup> `grib_handle` returned by the function is just an alias of `codes_handle`

Comment: `BytesMut::from(&[u8])` actually clones the original buffer, how else could you get a mutable from an immutable one? I think you are getting the pointer to that clone, dropping the clone releasing the memory, and passing the now dangling pointer to C.

Comment: I don't know that `fmemopen` well, but I guess that if you open it in read-only mode, you can safely cast your `*const u8` into `*mut u8`.

Comment: @rodrigo `let ptr = file.as_ptr() as *mut c_void` does indeed compile and work, I don't know why I haven't tried it yet. But according to [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66136) this cast should be avoided.
But coverting `file` into `BytesMut` before it is borrowed also works, so that solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I would say use a better http crate than request such as hyper

Comment: @Stargateur would you like to tell me more how using hyper will help in this case?

Comment: avoid stupid `Bytes` type from `bytes` crate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Try changing

```rust
let mode = "r".as_ptr() as *const c_char;
```

to

```rust
let mode = "r\0".as_ptr() as *const c_char;
```

Rust's &str is not null-terminated, while you're passing it to C where string literals are expected to be null-terminated.

2- Try the following implementation for open_with_fmemopen:

```rust
pub fn open_with_fmemopen(file: &Bytes) -> *mut FILE {
    unsafe {
        let obj = fmemopen(file.as_ref() as *const _ as _, file.len(), "r\0".as_ptr() as _);
        obj
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful sugesstion. Unfortunately the segfault still occurs.

Comment: I've added a second suggestion, I also noticed that BytesMut::from copies the data and is dropped at the end of the function.